# netlogo t-t communication example, chance to spread message slider

Tags: netlogo

I want to add a slider that shows the chance to spread the message to "Communication T-T Example" on Netlogo.

It's supposed to show the probability of the second turtle to receive the message from the first one who has the message, and it should be adjustable by the user.

Yet I don't know how I should modify the code in such a case.

I couldn't find any similar question in previous ones, I would appreciate your recommendations and helps, thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And note that a lot of us will be happy to help you, but please don't consider StackOverflow as some code shop where you can ask "how can I make this" and we describe full application to you. Anyway, no hard feelings and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: The "Communication-T-T Example" model is distributed with NetLogo. The source code is also available here: https://github.com/NetLogo/models/blob/master/Code%20Examples/Communication-T-T%20Example.nlogo

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you define your slider like this:

[image]

then it's just a matter of adding a simple condition to the `communicate` procedure:

```
to communicate
  if any? other turtles-here with [ message? ]
    and random 100 < transmission-probability
    [ set message? true ]
end
```

You could also define your probability to be from 0 to 1 and use `random-float 1.0` instead of `random 100`.